# Dwolla API - Transactions/listing "ClearingDate"

Tags: dwolla

I'd like some more clarity on this return value.  What does the clearing date actually represent?  Will this be absolutely accurate to bank statement deposit dates?  I'm guessing this is actually the date where the funds are sent to the bank for deposit.

How does Dwolla intend on helping clients get the data they need for reconciliation and accurate accounting?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that Dwolla is using a standard industry clearing date for transactions as a financial (payment network).  In financial terms a clearing date is the date of expected settlement of a transaction. The actual date can be different depending on activity surrounding the transaction.  A settlement date (clearing date) is typically accurate to bank statements once the transaction status changes from pending to settled.

If a transaction gets held up in the process the clearing date can change but you should expect to see the actual clear date on the statement match. I don't know if Dwolla updates the clear date or not but I am assuming they do.

There are also financial rules around what a clearing date is how many days a transaction is lawfully allowed to transpire.

Here are some links that talk about the clearing process which is what a clearing date represents.

[Intro to ACH (checks) system and rules by NACHA](https://www.nacha.org/Intro2ACH)

[General Clearing History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearing_%28finance%29)

Comment: Unfortunately, as you state, the clearing date doesn't always match bank statements.  So, unless Dwolla is getting this data another way, it's an expected clearing date, and thus, inaccurate.